# Being able to implement an interface only when the class inherit from a specific Class

Tags: java, inheritance, object

I'm programming with java.
Let's say I have an "MyInterface" interface, and a "MyClass" abstract class.

I want to ensure that every class implementing the "MyInterface" interface is inherited from "MyClass".
An inherited class from MyClass is perfectly able to NOT implement the "MyInterface" interface.

Is this possible ? Thanks.
I'm sorry if my english is bad but I'm french.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't do this directly.

Generics let you say something like this, if it helps:

```
public <T extends MyClass & MyInterface> void foo(T param) { /**/ }
```

So, you can only call foo() with parameters that are both MyClass and MyInterface.

Or, why not have two abstract base classes?

```
abstract class MyClass { /* stuff here */ }
abstract class MyInterfaceClass extends MyClass { /* empty */ }
```

Then, use MyInterfaceClass instead of MyInterface.

Or, if you just care about containers, write your own:

```
static class MyList extends ArrayList<MyInterface> {
    @Deprecated
    public boolean add(MyInterface obj) {
        assert obj instanceof MyClass;
        return super.add(obj);
    }

    public <T extends MyClass & MyInterface> boolean add(T obj) {
        return super.add(obj);
    }
}
```

Then, you will get a deprecation warning any time you make a mistake.

But my question remains - what problem are you trying to solve? Can you use more descriptive names instead of "Class" and "Interface"? Perhaps the right solution is something completely different..

Comment: I want to have different sub classes of MyClass. Some of them are storable in a List<MyInterface>, some of them are not.

Comment: Furthermore, having a class which implement the MyInterface and which isn't inherited from MyClass can lead to error. I want to avoid stupid errors while designing my classes.

Comment: I'm creating a video game, which have entities (Entity class). Some of them have real position (Spatial class), some of them have integer position (Tiled class), some of them don't have position at all (Logical class). Any entity can be updated (Updatable interface) or rendered (Drawable interface). Any Spatial can also be visible by other entities (Visible interface). Having a Visible Logical is dumb, just like having a Class which implement Updatable and isn't inherited from Entity. If I make a new Entity which inherit from B, I shouldn't have to write the interface that B already implement.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to ensure that every class
>   implementing the "MyInterface"
>   interface is inherited from "MyClass".

Nope. That's not possible. The whole point of an interface is to make it so that classes from different inheritance hierarchies can implement support for a pre-defined set of capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.  Any class can implement `MyInterface`.  There is no way to limit implementors to subclasses of `MyClass`.

If you really need a limitation like that I think you'll be stuck with having to not use an interface and instead use `MyClass` in place of an interface.